# WP Block Styles - Trigger JS when selecting a block style

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

Is there a 'right way' to run JS in the WP Block editor when a block style is selected?

I've searched through documentation and google but can't see an example of anyone running a JS script on a block style.

Essentially, I want to inject two elements around a `core/group` block, if it has a particular style.

My code works just fine on the front end, but in the backend, I can only get it working on a page refresh, after the block style is selected. Here is what i've got so far:

**Registerd by block style with php:**

```
register_block_style(
  'core/group',
  array(
    'name' => 'shape-pattern-1',
    'label' => 'Shape Pattern 1'
  )
);
```

**Function I want to run when style is in use**

```
var initialiseShapePatterns = function($block) {

    $block.prepend('<span class="shape-before"></span>');
    $block.append('<span class="shape-after"></span>');

    $(window).on('load scroll', function() {
        if( $block.isInViewport() ) {
            $block.addClass('animate');
        } else {
            $block.removeClass('animate');
        }
    });

}
```

**Calling function on front-end (working)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.is-style-shape-pattern-1, .is-style-shape-pattern-2, .is-style-shape-pattern-3').each(function() {
        initialiseShapePatterns( $(this) );
    });
});
```

**Calling function in block editor (only works if style is already selected on page load)**

```
if( wp.domReady ) {
    wp.domReady(function() {
        $('.is-style-shape-pattern-1, .is-style-shape-pattern-2, .is-style-shape-pattern-3').each(function() {
            initialiseShapePatterns( $(this) );
        });
    });
}
```

I get that I'm only telling it to run when the dom is loaded, but I can't find anything in the documentation about running code on style select.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In jquery, you can add event listners, which will trigger an action when a event happens.

The following code snippet will execute when a button with the id 'myButtonId' is clicked.

```
$( "#myButtonId" ).click(function() {
  //myButtonId was clicked.
  $('.is-style-shape-pattern-1, .is-style-shape-pattern-2, .is-style-shape-pattern-3').each(function() {
        initialiseShapePatterns( $(this) );
    });
});
```

You will need to set the id of the button which you want to trigger this function. You can do this with the html `id` attribute

```
<button id='myButtonId'> Button Text </button>
```

In wordpress you can add custom HTML.You mentioned blocks so i assume you are using the gutenburg block editor. This means that you can find the block 'custom HTML' and then put that html button in the custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Add an even listener to the clicked object when selecting style that does it for you. Something like this (change #styleselectbutton to the correct element).

```
$( "#styleselectbutton" ).click(function() {
      $('.is-style-shape-pattern-1, .is-style-shape-pattern-2, .is-style-shape-pattern-3').each(function() {
            initialiseShapePatterns( $(this) );
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like as follows..

```
function my_plugin_blocks() {

    wp_add_inline_script( 'wp-edit-post', "

    wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle( 'core/group', {
        name: 'shape-pattern-1',
        label: 'Shape Pattern 1',
    });

    jQuery.fn.isInViewport = function() {       
      var elementTop = jQuery(this).offset().top;
      var elementBottom = elementTop + jQuery(this).outerHeight();

      var viewportTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
      var viewportBottom = viewportTop + jQuery(window).height();

      return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
    };

    var initialiseShapePatterns = function(\$block) {

        if(\$block.find('> span.shape-before').length == 0)
            \$block.prepend('<span class=\"shape-before\"></span>');
        if(\$block.find('> span.shape-after').length == 0)
            \$block.append('<span class=\"shape-after\"></span>');
    };  

    const getBlockList = () => wp.data.select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlocks();
    let blockList = getBlockList();
    wp.data.subscribe(() => {
      const newBlockList = getBlockList();
      const blockListChanged = newBlockList !== blockList;
      blockList = newBlockList;
      if ( blockListChanged ) {
        jQuery('.is-style-shape-pattern-1, .is-style-shape-pattern-2, .is-style-shape-pattern-3').each(function() {
            initialiseShapePatterns( jQuery(this) );
        });
      }
    });

    function scrollcontent()
    {
        jQuery('.is-style-shape-pattern-1, .is-style-shape-pattern-2, .is-style-shape-pattern-3').each(function() {
            if(jQuery(this).isInViewport()) {
                jQuery(this).addClass('animate');
            } else {
                jQuery(this).removeClass('animate');
            }
        });
    };

    setTimeout(function(){
        scrollcontent(); 
        jQuery('.edit-post-layout__content').on('load scroll resize', function() { scrollcontent(); });
    }, 500); ");
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'my_plugin_blocks' );
```

Here i hooked script from `functions.php` and registerBlockStyle using `js` not `php`.You can use any other ways.

*I guess you need to write animate when content area scrolls not for window. Because content area is fixed in Wordpress block editor.*

Here the helpful docs:

[**Doc1**](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/8655)
[**Doc2**](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/)

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers were satisfying to me, so here's my solution. I am using a block called `section` and I want a trigger when the style variant `dark` is selected. I am using **WordPress 5.6**.

My first approach:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.block-editor-block-styles__item').forEach(
    (element) => addClickListener(element)
);

// get the title of the block to make sure to only target this block with the style variant 'dark' (because there might be other blocks which also have this variant name. 
const blockTitle = document.querySelector('.block-editor-block-card__title');

function addClickListener(styleButton) {
  styleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (blockTitle && blockTitle.textContent === 'Section') {

      // Get the right styleButton by the label that is assigned to it. 
      if(styleButton.getAttribute('aria-label') === 'Dark'){
        soSomething(); // Execute this function when the style 'Dark' is selected. 
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Now as you can tell, this approach is quite bad. It uses the title of the block that is rendered in some HTML and also the label of the style variant to apply an event listener to. It does work, but chances are the markup (HTML) of the editor will change in the future, breaking this code.

My second (**better**) approach:

```
// Checking for changes in the classNames to make changes to the bloc (only when the block is selected). 
if (props.isSelected) {
  const getCurrentBlock = () => wp.data.select('core/editor').getBlock(props.clientId);
  let oldBlock = getCurrentBlock();

  wp.data.subscribe(() => {
    const newBlock = getCurrentBlock();

    // Change this line with your classname and callback function. 
    whenStyleIsChanged('is-style-dark', () => doSomething() )

    function whenStyleIsChanged(style, callback) {
      if (newBlock?.attributes?.className?.includes(style) && !oldBlock?.attributes?.className?.includes(style)) {
        oldBlock = newBlock; // Reset to prevent never-ending recursion.
        callback()
      }
    }

  })
}
```

Not only is the second approach much cleaner and future-proof, it is also the 'Gutenberg way' (Redux in reality) and I can trigger my function only when my block style is changed, as opposed to whenever a click is registered on the "style button". This is done by comparing the classnames of the block before and after the update, in my case the class `is-style-dark`. Make sure to change this and the callback function accordingly.